# Signatures not changing automatically when switching accounts - Live Mail

Tags: windows-live-mail

I'm trying to set up a Live Mail client with multiple accounts and separate signatures for each account.

I have defined signatures in *options -> signatures -> advanced.*

Each account has one signature assigned and each signature is assigned to only one account.
I've additionally set a default signature, not assigned to any account.

When I'm creating a new message, a signature assigned to my default account is added automatically. When  I change the account in the top right drop-down menu, the signature doesn't change.

**Question:** How can I enable automatic switching of a signature while I'm picking different accounts in the drop-down menu?

This is a  [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/512608/how-to-automatically-add-signature-to-specific-email-accounts-outlook-2010), but I think I did everything they suggest and it's still not working. Maybe a difference between Outlook and Live Mail?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that there is no way to do that. It is also very annoying to try making a signature file in html, more if you want to add an image (a logo) and you don't want to have it with shadows because shadows are set by default. The only way that I have found to do that is adding the images in the background with the line:

```
<div style="width: 186px; text-align: left; height: 16px; background: url('C:\Users\Boss\Documents\Signatures\mylogo.jpg') no-repeat"></div>
```

Sorry that I wasn't o help to you but I guess that you have been fighting with the signature html files to avoid the shadows on the images. Hope it helps.

Comment: A general problem with "can't be done" answers is the reader doesn't know if that is definitive information or perhaps you just aren't familiar with a solution.  It's better to cite a source.